# Angular Docker Version JS file

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

I am using following docker file to build and host my angular project in serverless environment.

when angular create a build , it has index.html with path to all minified javascript. e.g. runtime.fc6cabb48741575b657e.js

I want to replace the file name with runtime.fc6cabb48741575b657e.**js?v=1.25**. How I can do this in dockerfile after build?

```
# Name the node stage "builder"
FROM node:10 AS builder
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app
# Copy all files from current directory to working dir in image
COPY . .
# install node modules and build assets
RUN npm i && npm run build -- --prod
# server environment
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/Demoproj /usr/share/nginx/html

ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 8080
CMD sh -c "envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```